# How to set an expiry on a cached Ruby search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function, which returns a list of ID's, in the [Rails caching guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) I can see that an expiration can be set on the cached results, but I have implemented my caching somewhat differently.

```
def provide_book_ids(search_param)
      @returned_ids ||= begin
        search = client.search(query: search_param, :reload => true)
        search.fetch
        search.options[:query] = search_str
        search.fetch(true)
        search.map(&:id)
      end
    end
```

What is the recomennded way to set a 10 minute cache expiry, when written as above?

Comment: What is client here? Some kind of API wrapper? Doesn't look like a Rails-connected thing to me, so there shouldn't be any caching automatically.

Comment: Client refers to Zendesk API. I'm pulling ID's in the above function, then using it to work with the object in Zendesk. My issue is the above search could return 1000's of ID', but the search params also change, so caching with Memoize eg is not suitable afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def provide_book_ids(search_param)
  @returned_ids = Rails.cache.fetch("zendesk_ids", expires_in: 10.minutes) do
      search = client.search(query: search_param, :reload => true)
      search.fetch
      search.options[:query] = search_str
      search.fetch(true)
      search.map(&:id)
    end
 end
```

I am assuming this code is part of some request-response cycle and not something else (for example a long running worker or some class that is initialized once in your app. In such a case you wouldn't want to use @returned_ids directly but instead call provide_book_ids to get the value, but from I understand that's not your scenario so provided approach above should work.